# How to match urls in app.yaml based on query parameters?

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I currently route any request where the path starts with `/app` to a single static file, that does routing using Javascript.

Now, I'd like to support Google's ajax crawling protocol, which means I have to return HTML snapshots at any url that starts with `/app` and ends with `?_escaped_fragment=`.

I have these two handlers:

```
- url: /app\?_escaped_fragment=
  script: main.app

- url: /app(/.*)?
  static_files: static/pages/app.html
  upload: static/pages/app\.html
```

But requests to `/app?_escaped_fragment=` are still routed to the static page. Is there a way to match the query parameters?

I know I can route `/app(/.*)?` to a script that returns either the static page, or a snapshot based on the presence of the query parameter, but serving static files is a lot cheaper, so I'd like only requests with the query parameter to hit my app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be nice, if you read the spec, the handlers section is for REGEXP matching on paths only, not query params. If you design your app using RESTful principles, you can easily convert your query param access to URI-based access. Just route based on `/app/escaped_fragment/.*` and in the handler function, inspect the rest of the path to find which specific resource of type escaped_fragment is being requested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'll have to hit a script then. I'd love to respond to requests to /app/*/_escaped_fragment_, but that won't work, because Google wants to send requests to `?_escaped_fragment=`. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry, I missed your use case itself, how embarrassing... Yes, if you can't control the request being done via query parameters, you will have to include a control flow branch in every handler. 

I'd suggest extending webapp2.RequestHandler with a function to respond to this special request pattern, subclassing all of your handlers through that class, and at the top of each doGet\doPost function, calling the member function of the superclass you defined which is responsible for checking for this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you'd do in app.yaml. Those requests should still be routed to your handlers, where they can check the request parameter and return either JSON or HTML as appropriate.

Comment: In that case, I find it weird that I can route based on path, but not query parameters within app.yaml.